# Unable to read sObject error when saving Record From a Lightning Component's Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to insert a record in a custom sObject 'Master_a__C' using lightning component. When i am clicking on save button, '**Unable to read sObject**' error is coming upon controller's logic. Below are all the source code files. 
Any help is appreciated.

Component File :

```
<aura:component controller=RandomWorkSpace_Cntrl'> 
       <aura:attribute name="master_a" type="Master_a__C" default="{'sObjectType' : 'Master_a__C', 'Name' : ''}"/>

<form>
    <ui:inputText aura:id="name" value="{!v.master_a.Name}"  />
    <ui:button press="c.saveMaster" label="save"/>
</form>

</aura:component>
```

RandomWorkSpace_Cntrl :

```
public with sharing class  RandomWorkSpace_Cntrl{

@AuraEnabled
public static Master_a__C saveRecord(Master_a__C mas){
    upsert mas; 
    return mas; 
} }
```

Controller.js :

```
({
saveMaster : function(component, event, helper) {

    var master = component.get("v.master_a"); 
    var action = component.get("c.saveRecord");
    action.setParams({"mas" : master});

    console.log("mastera ---->" + JSON.stringify(master));

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
       var state = response.getState();
        if(state == "SUCCESS" && component.isValid()){
           console.log("success") ;

        }
        else{
            console.log("failed  ::: " + response.getError()[0].message); // Unable to read sObject

        }

    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);


}})
```

Comment: Did you look at this thread - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112636/lightning-components-in-visualforce-unable-to-read-sobject

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error is due the case-sensitivity issue.It should haven been `sobjectType` instead of `sObjectType` in the default attribute of `master_a`

Always remember that attributes and it's values in component markup and variables you declare in controller.js and helper.js are all case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks Praveen. It was indeed  **sobjectType** instead of sObjectType.

Comment: Curse the lightning gods! Thanks so much for this answer, I would never have figured that out. I've always used `sObjectType` in apex and never encountered `sobjectType` lowercase 'o'. Dang.

Comment: Blerg, thank you stack overflow. Nothing like trying to guess the deviations from lower camel case in internal apex.

Answer (score 1):

When method in apex controller having parameter sObject:
 - Either set sobjectType attribute inside default in aura:attribute component Or 
   object should have Id to call server side method.

When method in apex controller having specific sObject eg. Account:
  - No need to declare sobjectType inside default attribute of aura attribute 
    component.

If above condition not satisfied it gives error unable to read sObject.