# Unable to read SObject error in Lightning Component when record has been queried from the database

Tags: lightning-aura-components, sobject

I had encountered the "Unable to read SObject" error when attempting to pass an SObject record from Lightning to an @AuraEnabled Apex method.

Based on this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129971/unable-to-read-sobject-error-when-saving-record-from-a-lightning-components-con), I first tried setting the "sobjectType". This was effecting when starting with a new record, but not when the record I wanted to save had first been queried from the database.

I knew I could stringify my record and pass the JSON string, which could then be deserialized in Apex, but running as a sys admin and using a very simple component, I should be able to successfully pass the SObject record directly into Apex.

Here is what I found...

The record from the database included an "attributes" attribute when viewing it stringified in the JavaScript console. This is not included when the component creates a new record.

> {"attributes":{"type":"Application__c","url":"/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Application__c/a0E2C000000RvHCUA0"},"Name":"test","Id":"a0E2C000000RvHCUA0"}

In order to get this SObject passed into Apex, I had to set "attributes" to null.

```
var appSobject = component.get("v.appSobject");
appSobject.attributes = null;
```

With or without setting "sobjectType", I was able to pass my queried record back into Apex when I cleared this "attributes" value before sending.

The error is also encountered when a query for the initial record traverses a relationship to include a related value, such as "Account__r.Name". In this case, I also had to set the "Account__r" attribute to null before passing the value into Apex.

I hope this information is helpful to someone in need.

Why do these attributes need to be set to null before passing the record back to Apex?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me .Have you raised a case ?

Comment: This appears to be related to my serializing and deserializing untyped in Apex before returning the Application__c record to Lightning, trying to use a custom Apex wrapper class to return all responses to Lightning. When working directly with the Application__c record (not first wrapping it in Apex as a generic object), I do not encounter this error.

Comment: Any reason you are using typed objects in first place? I find it much easier to use generic objects which i de/serialise manually in JS/Apex.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today... make sure 'sobjectType' in your attribute definition is the correct case. I had 'sObjectType' and it took me forever to figure out why it wasn't even calling the Apex controller.