# Unable to read sObject - Lightning Save Record

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Ok.

I have tried all the fixes listed:

[Unable to read sObject error when saving Record From a Lightning Component's Controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129971/unable-to-read-sobject-error-when-saving-record-from-a-lightning-components-con)

[Lightning Components in Visualforce - Unable to read sobject](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112636/lightning-components-in-visualforce-unable-to-read-sobject)

[Unable to read SObject error in Lightning Component when record has been queried from the database](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152577/unable-to-read-sobject-error-in-lightning-component-when-record-has-been-queried)

1. set sobjectType = 'NS__ObjectName__c'
2. set attributes = null

etc, etc, etc.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Some known facts:

1. The sObject is defined on the parent as:

   ```
    <aura:attribute name="theObject" type="NS__APINAME__c"
               description="The sObject we will be working with"/>
   ```

(actual names removed to protect the innocent, it is a custom object from a managed package)

2. the sObject is retrieved from the apex controller with a lookup relationship populated with the ID of the appropriate record. It is instantiated in the apex controller as follows

   ```
    return New NS__APINAME__C(LOOKUPFIELD__C = theId);
   ```
3. This sObject is passed into a child component as an attribute in the child component as such:

   ```
    <aura:attribute name="theObject" access="public" type="NS__APINAME__C" required="true"/>
   ```

The controller on the child component

```
({

    upsertObject : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.upsertTheObject");
        var o = component.get("v.theObject");

        //console.log(JSON.stringify(o));

        o.sobjectType = 'NS__APINAME__C';
        o.attributes = null;

        action.setParams({
            "obj": o //JSON.stringify(o)
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state == "SUCCESS" && component.isValid()){
                console.log("success") ;

            }
            else{
                console.log("failed  ::: " + response.getError()[0].message); 

            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }

})
```

4. The method in the apex controller is set to a concrete sObject as the parameter

The only way I have been able to get this to work is by JSON.stringify.

Any one have any other ideas?

**Apex method to get sObjectinstance**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static NS__NAME__c getObjectInstance(String lookupId) {
    return New NS_NAME__c(
            Name = 'Test',
            NS__LOOKUP__c = lookupId
    );
}
```

**Save method**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static NS__NAME__c upsertTheObject(NS__NAME__c obj) {
    //upsert theOrder;
    return obj;
}
```

**SoapBox** I am not sure if it is the mindset coming from Apex/VF or not, but the most basic, simple, things in Lightning have been buggy, not working, difficult to implement, code bloat, etc. So far I am not impressed. I hope that the complex stuff is easier and offsets the steep curve with the basics. I mean cmon, I have to roll my own input for an sObject Picklist, code cannot be shared, loading does not work, can't save an sObject, can get something to eat, but only if x, y, and z are done, but you absolutely cannot do it if e or j is done first, e and j must be done last, then z, then you can eat. Oh my

And to top it off its 1 degree outside and I do not have any hats anymore...

**I DO** however love the automatic re rendering of the elements and updating of the values etc so far. that part is much easier 
**End soapbox**

**AHHHHHHHHH**

I just found out that unless you define the attribute with ALL fields you will be using or Query for them, no matter what you do in your controller the values will NEVER be set or passed to the apex controller. What a PITA. If I have an input that sets "{!v.theObject.Name}" it should set the name of the dang object. But I guess since it is JS Name will not be defined unless I define it so i guess I get it...

Comment: I'll second that. It's been a tough sell to start learning it, even with the brilliant people they have working on it. (Thanks Doug!)

Comment: Yea, honestly it seems the complex stuff is much easier. Its just the stuff you *think* should be the most basic are sooooo difficult. I could have also picked an easier project to start learning on but a simple entry form that can be used in a popup on standard page layout as well as a Lightning Page element has taken  1 VF Page, 1 App, 3 components, 3 controllers, 2 helpers, and 2 css. The helpers and css are ALL duplicative. And All I have got is a billing address entry form lol.

Comment: I was not around for the start of VF and I bet the growing pains were similar....

Comment: Just curious... did you make sure that all references to the API name are cAsE-sEnSiTiVe? Unlike Apex, Lightning is incredibly ... obsessive-compulsive regarding that.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Yea, I tried with all lower case AND with case copied exactly fro the sObject API Name.....I wonder if it has something to do with the field being in a managed package since all the other workarounds seemed to work for others but they were using non Namespaced objects in their examples.

Comment: Can you share your Apex controller signature

Comment: @manjit_singh - Added. I think my issue is that I need to default the sObject in the lightning controller with ALL field I need first. It seems that unless I specify them they will not be present....

Comment: @Eric Did you try adding default attribute to the aura:attribute name: `theObject`. I had the same problem earlier with one of my code and adding default fixed the issue. eg: `<aura:attribute name="theObject" type="NS__APINAME__c"
            description="The sObject we will be working with" default="{sobjectType:'NS__APINAME__c'}"/>`. Let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: @Praveen - Yup see my answer below. It worked for first save but subsequent returned the same error. Only JSON.stringify() seems to work

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE - Seems the below still does not work**

> If I do the below, it sends to server the first time, but does not get the appropriate value back (setting the attribute using the returnValue)so the fields do not update and a subsequent save return the same error. Though I had it but nope. Back to JSON.stringify

<s>Ok. I figured it out.......</s>

Seems the way you set the attribute makes all the difference

When I do this everything works correctly, Including saving of the fields that you do not specifically set.....

```
<aura:attribute name="theObject" type="NS__APINAME__c" 
     default="{'sobjectType' : 'NS__NAME__c'}" 
     description="The sObject we will be working with"
 />
```

Basically if you do not define a default and use an apex controller method to return a new instance of the sObject, it WILL NOT work

Comment: you could have just set the `{ attributes: { type: "some sobject type" }}` in your object before passing it to the back end, it would automatically see it as an SObject with those values set after deserializing it to SObject.class