# Lightning Component: Unable to read SObject

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I've looked through the various questions here on this topic but still can't find the solution.

I'm trying to upsert a list of records, but keep getting the above error. Code snippets below, any suggestions appreciated.

```
<div class="slds-p-around--small slds-align--absolute-center">
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick="{!c.createTimesheet}" />
</div>
```

controller

```
createTimesheet : function(component, event, helper){
    var newTimesheet = component.get("v.timesheets");
    helper.createTimesheet(component, newTimesheet);
},
```

helper

```
    createTimesheet : function(component, timesheets){
    this.upsertTimesheets(component, timesheets, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                             errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
        timesheets.push(response.getReturnValue());
        component.set("v.timesheets", timesheets);
    });
},

upsertTimesheets : function(component, timesheets, callback){
    var action = component.get("c.saveTimesheets");
    timesheets.sobjectType = 'Timesheet_Unit__c';
    action.setParams({"timesheets": timesheets});
    if(callback){
        action.setCallback(this, callback);
    }
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Comment: Can you show your aura:attribute ?

Comment: Two relevant questions: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130878/why-am-i-unable-to-pass-an-opportunity-from-a-lightning-component-into-an-aurae and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112636/lightning-components-in-visualforce-unable-to-read-sobject - Resolution 1. sobjectType and 2. JSON string those are the two know solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to get this working using JSON.stringify e.g.

```
action.setParams({"timesheets": JSON.stringify(timesheets)});
```

and then deserialising in the controller

Comment: Glad you got it working. I am looking forward to when they fix this and the issue with empty variables in classes sent to client. I can then clean up my code a lot

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me as well.  I had same issue then used the JSON.sringify and it worked.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thx.