# How to pass sobject list to apex from lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

```
SaveAccessRequest : function(component, event, helper) {
    var ARLIlist = component.get("v.AccessRequestLineItems");
    var action = component.get("c.getSaveRecord");
    var accessreq = component.get("v.AccessRequest");
    action.setParams({"AR":accessreq,
                     "ARLI":ARLIlist});
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Here "AccessRequestLineItems" & "AccessRequest" is an sobject array & sobject defined on the component. while I invoke this function neither received an error nor the function on apex is invoked. can anyone help me in resolving the issue?

**Apex code**

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static void getSaveRecord(Access_Request__c AR,List<Access_Request_Line_Item__c> ARLI){
    system.debug('====>'+ARLI);
    Insert AR;
    system.debug('====>'+ARLI);
    for(Integer i=0; i<ARLI.size(); i++){
        ARLI[i].Access_Request_ID__c = AR.id;
    }
    Insert ARLI;
    system.debug('====>'+ARLI[0].id);

}
```

Also tried with return type

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static Access_Request__c getSaveRecord(Access_Request__c AR,List<Access_Request_Line_Item__c> ARLI){
    system.debug('====>'+ARLI);
    Insert AR;
    system.debug('====>'+ARLI);
    for(Integer i=0; i<ARLI.size(); i++){
        ARLI[i].Access_Request_ID__c = AR.id;
    }
    Insert ARLI;
    system.debug('====>'+ARLI[0].id);
    return AR;
}
```

Comment: You're not setting a callback, so how do you know it's not doing anything?

Comment: @sfdcfox I have debug logs in the apex. I could have received logs once the function is invoked.

Comment: did you add controller in component. Because it will not give any error  if you not add that. Also share your apex controller code.

Comment: @TusharSharma Yes, i have added controller on the component.

Comment: @TusharSharma Added controller.

Comment: How is the saveaccessrequest function getting called ? From a button/ init ??

Comment: @Rao HTML button using onclick attribute.

Comment: can you post your component code? Could be a silly question, do you have the controller class in the component?

Comment: @Rao If i haven't referenced controller in component controllerjs would through an error on invoking the function.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but I see an extremely common mistake in your code - lack of transaction control. Please consider inserting your parent and child records in one transaction as per this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm
Not following this pattern you may occasionally end up with records with not children, or if you use database rollbacks some other side effects.

Comment: Also, do you have Lightning debug mode enabled? I've been getting lots of "Unable to read sObject" exceptions. There are many tricks you may need to do, like remove relational fields, set a type and more: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112636/lightning-components-in-visualforce-unable-to-read-sobject

Comment: Look out my explanation at the bottom. Hope it will help you out. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this post. 
I was able to pass the sobject and sobject array using json.encode util.I have used account sobject for the sake of testing.

Passing a sobject param was/ is causing error in Lightning: 
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XW6AAM

**component:**

```
<aura:component controller="Saveaccesscontroller">
    <aura:attribute name="AccountItems" type="Account[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="Accountval" type="Account" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Account',
                         'Name': 'test'}"/>

     <button type="button" onclick="{!c.SaveAccessRequest}">Click Me!</button> 
</aura:component>
```

**controller:**
I have queried the account list and passed it to the getReturnValue method in the server side controller.

```
({
    SaveAccessRequest : function(component, event, helper) {      
        var ARLIlist = component.get("v.AccountItems");
        var accessreq = component.get("v.Accountval");
        var queryaction = component.get("c.queryRecord");
        queryaction.setCallback(this, function(response) {            
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.AccountItems",response.getReturnValue());
                var action = component.get("c.getSaveRecord");
                action.setParams({"AR":$A.util.json.encode(accessreq),
                                  "ARLI":$A.util.json.encode(component.get("v.AccountItems"))});
                $A.enqueueAction(action);
             }
        });    
        $A.enqueueAction(queryaction);              

        }
})
```

**Apex controller:**

> Define the param as string and use the convertJSONToListOfSObject
>   method to from the post above to convert the string to list

```
 public class Saveaccesscontroller {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void getSaveRecord(String AR,String ARLI){
        system.debug('====>'+ARLI);
         List<SObject> newSObjectsList = convertJSONToListOfSObject(ARLI);
        system.debug('====>'+newSObjectsList);
        system.debug('====>'+AR);
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<account> queryRecord(){
        return [select id,name from Account limit 5];
    }

     private static List<SObject> convertJSONToListOfSObject(String json) {
        object[] values = (object[])System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(json);

        List<SObject> newSObjectsList = new List<SObject>();
        for (Object v : values) {
            Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)v;
            Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get((String)m.get('sobjectType'));

            SObject o = targetType.newSObject();

            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = targetType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            for (String fieldName : m.keySet()) {
                // Filter out any psuedo fields such as LastNameLocal
                Schema.SObjectField fi = fields.get(fieldName);
                if (fi != null) {
                    if (fi.getDescribe().isCreateable() && fi.getDescribe().isUpdateable()) {
                        o.put(fieldName, m.get(fieldName)); 
                    }
                }
            }

            newSObjectsList.add(o);
        }

        return newSObjectsList;
    }
}
```

**Debug logs:**

09:38:31.3 (4142574)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|**DEBUG|====>[{"Id":"001d000001xDnrmAAC","Name":"Smith Enterprises"},{"Id":"001d0000026DD5JAAW","Name":"test"},{"Id":"001d000001StO98AAF","Name":"abc"},{"Id":"001d000001StOT1AAN","Name":"abc"},{"Id":"001d000000ySkIvAAK","Name":"TEST"}]**
09:38:31.3 (4172328)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[5]
09:38:31.3 (4180526)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[5]|Bytes:44
09:38:31.3 (4189407)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|
**09:38:31.3 (4198943)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|====>{"sobjectType":"Account","Name":"test"}**

Comment: Hi Rao, i got this error on using $A.util.json.encode.                                  This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'encode' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {markup://c:AccessRequest_cmp}

Comment: FYI I'm trying to pass a sobject list to apex, not a string. Thank you for quick responses.

Comment: @Venky I have passed the sobject (Account) list, look at the AccountItems attribute in the component, I have passed it as a string to the controller byusing json.encode utility. For some reason the array of account is coming up as null, same issue I faced when I was passing a date for which I converted the date into string and type casted it later in the apex controller to be a date.

Comment: Is there any mistake in below code.

Comment: Do you ask if there is error in the code i poated as an answer?? I will double check it but as far as i know i did a copy paste

Comment: i got this error on using $A.util.json.encode. This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'encode' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {markup://c:AccessRequest_cmp}

Comment: i'm recieving the above error

Comment: I'm surprised that noone has mentioned that Lightning Components don't support Apex Lists as Attribute types, BUT they DO support Arrays. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_collection.htm

Answer (score 2):

**Component:**

```
    <aura:component controller="Saveaccesscontroller">
    <aura:attribute name="AccountItems" type="Account[]" default="{'name' : 'karthik'}" />
    <aura:attribute name="Accountval" type="Account" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Account',
                                                              'Name': 'test'}"/>
    <ui:button label="ClickMe" press="{!c.SaveAccessRequest}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**controller:**

I have queried the account list and passed it to the getReturnValue method in the server side controller.

```
    ({
    SaveAccessRequest : function(component, event, helper) {      
        var ARLIlist = component.get("v.AccountItems");
        var accessreq = component.get("v.Accountval");
        var queryaction = component.get("c.queryRecord");
        queryaction.setCallback(this, function(response) {            
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.AccountItems",response.getReturnValue());
                var ARLIlist = component.get("v.AccountItems");
                var action = component.get("c.getSaveRecord");
                action.setParams({"AR":accessreq,
                                  "ARLI":component.get("v.AccountItems")});
                action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                    var state = response.getState();
                }) 
                $A.enqueueAction(action);
            }
        });    
        $A.enqueueAction(queryaction);              

    }
})
```

**Apex code:**

Here i pass sObject List into Apex

```
    public class Saveaccesscontroller {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void getSaveRecord(Account AR,List<Account> ARLI){
        system.debug('====>'+AR);
        Insert AR;
        system.debug('AccountList====>'+ARLI); 

        for(Integer i=0; i<ARLI.size(); i++){
            ARLI[i].Name = AR.Name;
        }
        update ARLI;
        system.debug('====>'+ARLI[0].Name);
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<account> queryRecord(){
        return [select id,name from Account limit 5];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this few days back. Simply just by stringifying & deserializing the list.

Pass your params as string using JSON.stringify function.

```
SaveAccessRequest : function(component, event, helper) {
    var ARLIlist = component.get("v.AccessRequestLineItems");
    var action = component.get("c.getSaveRecord");
    var accessreq = component.get("v.AccessRequest");
var ARLIlistAsString = JSON.stringify(ARLIlist);
var accessreqAsString = JSON.stringify(accessreq);
    action.setParams({"ARAsString":accessreqAsString,
                     "ARLIAsString":ARLIlistAsString});
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Update your apex method like this: Take the inputs as string and use JSON.deserialize to convert it back to Object or List.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void getSaveRecord(String ARAsString, String ARLIAsString){

Access_Request__c AR = JSON.deserialize(ARAsString, Access_Request__c.class);
List<Access_Request_Line_Item__c> ARLI = JSON.deserialize(ARLIAsString, List<Access_Request_Line_Item__c>.class);
    Insert AR;
    system.debug('====>'+ARLI);
    for(Integer i=0; i<ARLI.size(); i++){
        ARLI[i].Access_Request_ID__c = AR.id;
    }
    Insert ARLI;
    system.debug('====>'+ARLI[0].id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the similar thing in my component. Instead of passing of type List I am passing JSON string to method. Convert your list attribute into JSON string in lightning code (JSON.stringify()) and pass it to apex method as method parameter (String). In apex method deserialize the JSON string into required List.

This is working fine for me. In the same way I am passing List of object from component to apex methods. JSON string > Apex method > deserialize.